# Checking if my window listener is working

Tags: java, swing, window, listener

I'm trying to see if my window listener is working. I was hoping to print out a message in the console before I call dispose in the windowClosed method but it doesn't print anything. I'm not really sure if I'm doing something wrong - is there a way to check?

```
    public class MyClass extends JFrame {
    . . . 
             this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

             @Override
             public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                 System.out.println("I'm in the listener");
                 dispose();
             }
        });

    . . .
}
```

Comment: That should work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `windowClosing`, which is called when the user tries to close the window. `windowClosed` is called *after* the window has been disposed, so it doesn't make sense to try to dispose it from there.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that! I changed it to windowClosing and it worked just fine. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

`windowClosing` is always fired.
`windowClosed` will be fired when you use:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

But the overridden method should be like this,

```
           @Override
           public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
               System.out.println("I'm in the listener");
               System.exit(0);
           }
      });
```

Here you can not use `dispose()` method since this method will be called after the frame is disposed.
If `dispose()` method is called then this will make `windowClosed()` method execute infinitely.